# Does Overwhelming Impact replace all instances of slow, or just from one source?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

So I'm levelling up a Knight for a friend, who's very Hammer Lock-down and I was looking at taking Overwhelming Impact.

The basic question is if he's slowing opponents via both [Defend the Line](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12664) and [Hindering Shield](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2862)*, and takes [Overwhelming Impact](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2532), does that let him Daze the enemy instead of slowing with Hindering Shield, and keep the slow from  Hold the Line, or does it Daze instead of all slow effects?

Slow by itself isn't a huge deal, but there's a lot of follow on effects if you have the right feats/abilities, which this Knight does, and I'm not even sure where to look in the books for how this would be handled.

*He doesn't have Hindering Shield yet, but he has slide 1 from Mark of storm and a Lightning weapon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact language of Overwhelming Impact is: (emphasis mine)

> Whenever you use a hammer to hit an enemy with a melee attack, and that attack would slow the enemy, you ***can*** instead daze the enemy for the same duration.

As such, converting a slow to a daze is entirely optional.

In addition, Overwhelming Impact does not care about the source of the slow -- only that the triggering attack would slow the enemy -- so you are correct that both *Defend the Line* and *Hindering Shield* are valid sources of a slow which *can* but *does not have to* be converted into daze.

With both of those sources applying a slow, you can reliably *daze and slow* enemies.

Now, some DMs may take issue with Hindering Shield's slow qualifying, as it triggers off of the slide, not the hit, and Overwhelming Impact wants the attack to slow, not a separate triggered effect (hindering shield) triggered by a separate effect (mark of storm) triggered by the attack. Common ruling allows for these to all work together recursively without an issue, but in the event your DM disagrees, I'd recommend just converting the slow from Defend the Line to dazed, while keeping the slow from Hindering Shield.